# É possível utilizar duas id's iguais em uma mesma tabela?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma situação que preciso tirar uma dúvida. Eu tenho uma tabela conforme abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE confrontos(  
    id_confrontos INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    dt_confronto DATE NOT NULL,
    id_estadios INT NOT NULL,
    ***id_clubes*** INT NOT NULL,
    ***id_clubes*** INT NOT NULL,
    id_treinadores INT NOT NULL,
    escore1 INT NOT NULL,
    escore2 INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_confrontos PRIMARY KEY(id_confrontos),
    CONSTRAINT FK_confrontos_estadios foreign key (id_estadios)   
        REFERENCES estadios (id_estadios),
    CONSTRAINT FK_confrontos_clubes foreign key (id_clubes)
        REFERENCES clubes (id_clubes),
    CONSTRAINT FK_confrontos_treinadores foreign key (id_treinadores)
        REFERENCES treinadores (id_treinadores)
);
```

Já vi que o MySql não permite criar esta tabela por duplicidade no campo `id_clubes`. Qual seria a melhor maneira de criar esta tabela?

Comment: Depende o que você precisa fazer. Por que a tabela iria ter duas colunas com `id_clubes`? Por que não renomear as colunas para `clube_a` e `clube_b`, por exemplo?

Comment: faça como fez com o `escore`.. use `id_clube1` ou `id_clube_mandante` ou algo do tipo..

Comment: no caso o problema é a duplicação do nome... você pode mudar para Ex: id_clube_mandante e id_clube_visitante

Comment: Ou... você cria uma tabela de relacionamento `[Id_Confronto | id_Clube]` e assim você poderá ter `N` clubes no mesmo confronto :P

Comment: Obrigado pessoal pelas dicas, vou testar aqui

Answer (score 0):

voce precisa criar uma table auxiliar entre confrontos e times, exemplo tabela timesquevaojogar nela vai ter a id do confronto e a id do time, como vai funcionar

controntoid 1 time 1

controntoid 1 time 2

e na tabela confroto vc faz a referencia a essa tabela

```
CREATE TABLE timesquevaojogar(  
    id_Timesquevaojogar
    id_confrontos
    id_clubes
```

caso queira pesquisar mais sobre isso procure por relacao `n para n`

Comment: Mas se sempre são só dois times que jogam, por que criar uma relação N:N? Não é mais fácil ter duas colunas?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss separando em uma auxiliar tanto melhora na pesquisa, como nas boas praticas do sql, fora que no caso dele ele deveria colocar a pontuacao do jogo na outro tabela tambem, pq ele pode fazer um datamine sobre o team A e ver as estaticas e afins... o assunto e longo mas nao impede de ter duas colunas tambem

Comment: recomendo a leitura tambem(primeiro artigo que eu vi) https://hackernoon.com/mysql-tutorial-example-relation-foreign-key-database-funtion-join-table-query-one-namy-nest-41dd09648fbd

Comment: Não entendo o que seria "boas práticas do SQL". Na minha opinião, permitir uma relação N:N em algo que não é N:N pode trazer mais problemas do que benefícios, tal como ter confrontos com 1 time, ou mais do que dois. Conseguiria adicionar na resposta algumas vantagens que vê fazendo assim?

Comment: Só estou querendo aprender com base em afirmações que não são "achismos". Você tem algum material de onde concluiu sobre essa diferença de performance ou algum teste que realizou?

Comment: se vc quer saber quantas vezes o team A jogou qual query vai executar com melhor perfomace, uma onde exite a id com index ou uma tabela que existe duas row contendo a informacao da id? o select com index é muito mais rapido do que uma busca em duas rows com numeros inteiros

Comment: usar 2 colunas vc deixa a tabela totalmente independente, no back-end vc sempre vai precisar comprar a duas tabelas

Comment: seguindo o exemplo dado, caso ele queira colocar tecnico do team a e b, sao mais duas colunas extras, faltas do team a e b mais duas colunas extras...

Comment: quanto mais colunas na tabela mais lento é a pesquisa e resultado

Comment: se quiser ir para o chat eu posso explicar passo a passo e dar exemplos praticos do meu dia a dia.

Comment: Já está lá, na verdade: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha